# Finding 3 or more duplicates in array

Tags: c++

I need write a program which checks if there are 3 or more matching numbers in an array. My code works fine until there is an array like "2 2 3 3 5 5 4 4 1 1", then it approves that there are 3 or more duplicates in the array which is not true. Maybe someone knows a simple solution which would help me? Or do I need to overwrite my code?
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void funk(int n, int a[], int &kiek);
int main()
{
    int n, a[101],kiek=0;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        cin >> a[i];
    }
    funk(n, a, kiek);
    if (kiek > 2) {
        cout << "TAIP";
    }
    else
        cout << "NE";
}
void funk(int n, int a[], int &kiek)//funkcijos kūnas
{
    int j;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j])
                kiek++;
            cout << kiek;

        }
    }
}
```

This is the input:

```
10
2 2 3 3 5 5 4 4 1 1
```

This is the output I need to get:

```
NE
```

Comment: what is the meaning of `NE` and `TAIP` ? For that input you expected a `TAIP` ?

Comment: You just need to reset `kiek` to zero after each `for (j = ...)` loop.

Comment: The program needs to print `NE` if there aren't 3 or more matching numbers and `YES` if there are.

Comment: Why don't you use the count() function and check whether the return is equal to 3 or not as you are in C++ ?

Comment: Sort the input, then scan.  If that isn't fast enough, build a histogram using a `std::unoredered_map` and then scan that.

Comment: If you have a 100 numbers, you will loop over 5000 times.  If 1000 numbers, 500,000+ times in a loop.  Just to warn you, the solution you came up with, even though it may solve your problem, would be unacceptable in most scenarios.

Comment: Histogram using a map is absolutely the way to go

Comment: @cocool97 because calling count for each element in the array would be terribly inefficient ? Only one pass through the array is needed

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I don't think this is worth than the given solution...

Answer (score 2):

The problem that your code has is:

You are comparing any 2 numbers and never reset the counter. So if there is an 1 1, you are increasing the counter. If there is then an 2 2 you are also increasing the counter. And for the final 3 3 you also increase the same counter. Then it is 3. Although there are only 2 same values. This can never work. What you could do is

- Read all values
- Count the frequency of EACH different value
- Check if the frequency of the values
- If any of the counts is greater than 2, then show corresponding message
- Show count of each value

I will show you the "more-modern" C++ approach and will use C++ algorithms for the below example solution.

First we will get the number of values to work with from the user. We will store the values in a `std::vector`. And, we use `std::copy_n` to copy the values from `std::cin` to our `std::vector`. For that we will use the `std::istream_iterator` that will iterate over the elements given by the user. So, we use a simple one-liner to read all values from the user.

Next is the frequency counting. For this we have a standard solution in C++. You will find it in dozens of places in the net. We will use a `std::map`. The key is the integer that we read into the vector and the value is the counter. With the `std::map`'s index operator `[]` we add a value to the map, if it is not yet existing. With the ++ we simply do the counting, whether the value was already in the `std::map` or has just been added. Also this is a very simple one-liner.

Then, we check, if any of the counts is greater than 2. For this we will use the STL algorithm `std::any_of` with a very simple lambda. With that, we can create your desired result.

Last, but not least, we show all values and their count, if the count is greater than 2. This we do with an ultra simple range based for loop. We extract the values out of the counter-`std::map` using structered bindings.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

    // Give instructions
    std::cout << "How many values do you want do read? Please specify: ";

    // Read the number of values to enter
    size_t numberOfValues{ 0U }; std::cin >> numberOfValues;


    // Read the given number of values from std::cin
    std::vector <int> values(numberOfValues);
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), numberOfValues, values.begin());

    // Count each value
    std::map<int, size_t> counter{};
    std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), [&counter](const int& i) { counter[i]++; });

    // Check, if any count is bigger than 2
    if (std::any_of(counter.begin(), counter.end(), [](const std::pair<int, size_t> & c) { return c.second > 2; }))
        std::cout << "TAIP\n";
    else
        std::cout << "NE\n";


    // Look, if there is any number with a count bigger than 2 and show the result
    for (const auto& [value, count] : counter)
        if (count > 2) std::cout << value << " --> " << count << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this gives you an idea on how this could be done . . .